# How do I replace or remove these elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, tags, replace, element

I've created the function below to create a load of video elements but how can I get javascript to delete it again or replace elements after these have been loaded? I've got another two functions like this that just load different videos. I want these elements to dissapear when either one of the other two function is called, so the new video elements can be seen.

```
function createVideo1(){
//alert("createSmallVideo has been called");  
var video = document.createElement("video");
video.setAttribute("id", "VideoElement");
video.setAttribute("src", "videos/surfing with friends.ogv");
video.setAttribute("controls", ""); 
video.setAttribute("width", "480");
video.setAttribute("height", "300");
document.getElementById("VideoContainer").appendChild(video);
video.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

`document.getElementById("VideoContainer").appendChild(video);`

With

```
var container = document.getElementById("VideoContainer");
container.replaceChild(video, container.firstElementChild);
```

This way your simply replacing the video element that's already there with a new video element.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the current video element that you created with this function.  Just call it before you create a new video element and insert it.

```
function removeVideo() {
    var video = document.getElementById("videoElement");
    video.parentNode.removeChild(video);
}
```